# wsdl service tag multiple url's

Tags: wsdl

can i specify 2 locations for a single portType operation in the service tag ? Basically this means that the client would call say url1 if it supports soap binding and url2 for some other bindings.

---

```
<wsdl:service name="NewService">
    <wsdl:port name="NewPort" binding="tns:NewBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://url1"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="NewPort" binding="tns:NewBinding2">
        <soap12:address location="http://url2"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

can't i do something like this ? where you can access NewPort operation through either url1 or url2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
<wsdl:service name="NewService">
    <wsdl:port name="NewPort" binding="tns:NewBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://url1"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="NewPort2" binding="tns:NewBinding2">
        <soap12:address location="http://url2"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Both bindings can refer to the same `portType`.

---

Full WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
    xmlns:tns="http://new.webservice.namespace" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
    targetNamespace="http://new.webservice.namespace">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://new.webservice.namespace" elementFormDefault="qualified"/>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="NewMessageRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" type="xs:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="NewMessageResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" type="xs:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="NewPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="NewOperation">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:NewMessageRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:NewMessageResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="NewBinding" type="tns:NewPortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="NewOperation">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:#NewOperation"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="NewBinding2" type="tns:NewPortType">
        <soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="NewOperation">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:#NewOperation" soapActionRequired="true" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="NewService">
        <wsdl:port name="NewPort" binding="tns:NewBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://url1"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="NewPort2" binding="tns:NewBinding2">
            <soap12:address location="http://url2"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: oh no both should be the same port operation. you have used two different ports. NewPort and NePort2

Comment: Sorry, you have that wrong. A `portType` defines the operations. A `binding` associates a `portType` with parameters specific to the communication technology used. The `service` element contains `port` elements which associate the binding with addressing information.

Comment: yeah i know that. But i want to allow the client have access through 2 different binding technologies. One can be soap and the other something else say ABC.